# Mongo to MySQL converting in Pentaho PDI

Tags: mysql, mongodb, pentaho

I created on transformation in Pentaho PDI which transfers from my Mongo collections into MySQL. For this I used Mongodb input and table output.  In the table output I selected truncate table true. Now my problem is listed below:

1. I want to run my transformation in every 5min. because my collection update every 5      min.
2. I want to insert only new added documents in MySQL table, for checking newly added documents. I set status key and it was set to 1 and after processing I updated it to 0.
3. Sometimes my collections contained nested data.  How is the nested data get to MySQL

I'm useing Pentaho Data Integration Community Edition 4.4.0

Comment: Hi, I solved my nested JSON issues using UDJC but how to add new documents in mysql tables without truncating tables?

Answer (score 0):

First, I strongly recommend you to use the Pentaho Big Data version: 1.3.3.1 because retreiving from MongoDB Input is extremely easy.

Instead of check the option 'truncate table' in the Table Output, create an 'Execute Sql' step before the MongoDB Input with a delete statement (delete all modified elements, for example) and in your MongoDB Input in the 'Query Expression (JSON) just put you want to retreive documents with status key = 1